# HAL_UART_Receive function's size parameter

Tags: c, uart, gpio, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to receive data with STM32F407 by using UART. I've realized that when I'd receive a data, I don't know it's size. Because of this, the code doesn't work when I enter the third parameter like this:

```
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart4, (uint8_t*)data, strlen(data),100);
```

How can I solve this in poll method?

Code explanation: If received data is 1, led D12 turns on. Numbers from 1 up to 4 triggers different pins/leds. And 0 turns off all.

Code:

```
char data[50];
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_UART_Receive(&huart4, (uint8_t*)data, strlen(data), 100);

      if(strcmp(data,"1")==0){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      }
      if(strcmp(data,"2")==0){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      }
      if(strcmp(data,"3")==0){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      }
      if(strcmp(data,"4")==0){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      }
      if(strcmp(data,"0")==0){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      }
      else{
          continue;
      }
  }
```

Comment: `strcmp(data,"1")` Do you send nul-terminated strings?

Comment: Your read request is for 50 bytes and the read buffer is not initialized. So your string comparisons of just a single character are suspect. Instead, try zeroing out the buffer first, and then read just 1 byte (since that is the length of the message you're expecting). OR ***debug your existing code*** by dumping the contents of the buffer (in hexadecimal representation not text) after the read but before the *string* comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their help. I've handled the issues. This is the code:

```
while (1)
  {
      char data[10];
          HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t*)data, 10, 1500);

          //char data[50];
          // HAL_UART_Receive(&huart4, (uint8_t*)data, strlen(data), 1500);

          if(IS_CONTAIN(data,'1')==1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }
          if(IS_CONTAIN(data,'2')==1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }
          if(IS_CONTAIN(data,'3')==1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }
          if(IS_CONTAIN(data,'4')==1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          }
          if(IS_CONTAIN(data,'0')==1){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          }
          else{
              continue;
          }
          memset(data, 0, 10*sizeof(data[0]));
          HAL_Delay(1500);
  }
```

IS_CONTAIN function:

```
int IS_CONTAIN(char* num,char parameter){//Çalışıyor
    int state = strlen(num);
    int i=0;
    while(i+1<=state){
        if(num[i]==parameter){
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

libs: string.h

Comment: Low-quality solution. You still don't have a proper string during very first iteration of the loop, yet there's a string operation. (IOW you ask for advice, but then are unable or unwilling to apply simple, clear, & correct advice, or misapply that advice.) The delay at the end of the loop may be questionable/unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you only seem to try and recieve on byte of data, so using a size of 1 should work. Some usual solutions to this kind of problem is either use a first fixed-sized message to send the size of the message you are going to send, or to read it byte per byte and terminate it by either NULL byte or EOT (ascii code 4).

Comment: Firstly, thanks for reply. I've also tried that but it hasn't work. When I remove the "==0" which is end of the strcmp(), all leds turn on together and naturally I can't control them. I am not sure if there is a mistake on if comparisions.

Comment: @busragulen :  "*I am not sure if there is a mistake on if comparisions.*" -- Of course there is. That's why your code doesn't behave as you expect. A string is a well-defined data construct. There's no way you have guaranteed that there's a *string* in that buffer. There may be  zero, one, or more received characters in that buffer, but that does not automatically make it a *string* per programming convention (i.e. null terminated).